# How to download binaries for MS ODBC18 Driver?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, unixodbc

I need to install the MS ODBC 18 Driver into Amazon Linux 2 (for EC2). The steps here cannot be completed due to network restrictions: [Microsoft ODBC 18](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=redhat18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline#18). Also the package needs to be installed while running our pipeline; the binaries need to be stored in Artifactory.

How can I obtain the binaries for MS ODBC 18 Driver without going through the above install steps? The only download I can find anywhere is an installer that provides a .msi.

Comment: Download packages from here, check dependencies, download, upload to Amazon and install: https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/9/prod/Packages/m/

Comment: That link is exactly what I was looking for. If you leave it as an answer I will mark it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure for offline install is next:

1. From the link you provide you get the URL of repo (some walk around the web site is involved): https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/9/prod/Packages/m/
2. You download the package somewhere on your site.
3. You must check the dependencies of this package (example)

   `rpm -qpR msodbcsql18-18.3.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm`
4. Download dependent packages (is any)
5. Repeat the procedure with new packages. BTW some packages are part of OS and it is not required to download them.
6. Upload package(s) in Amazon
7. Do local install of packages:

   `yum localinstall  msodbcsql18-18.3.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm otherpackage....`
8. Done :)